# pywinauto GUI automation failing on windows servers

Tags: python-3.x, windows-server-2012-r2, pywinauto

I have developed a Desktop Application (GUI) Automation using **pywinauto**. I am using the python version 3.6 on a windows machine. It works perfectly fine when I run in Microsoft Server directly. But I wanted to run this automation script on windows servers by executing the script via a Scheduler. The script is unable to open the application. I have read the documentation on https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html

But I am not sure which route to take to solve this issue. I am new to **pywinauto**. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both VNC or proper customization of RDP are fine. Using silent methods is more risky and hard to debug especially if you're new in this area. Please provide more details in your question. I don't see exact problem. StackOverflow is for detailed questions, not for opinion based ones or recommendations.

Comment: I am not using any silent methods. I am using methods like select(), send_keys(), click_input() etc. When I run the script on Windows Server directly, it's working fine as expected. But when I run from a scheduler(tidal) (not Windows Scheduler), it's not working. It goes to exception block for not able to recognise the widow. How to make the automation run from a scheduler?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this commercial scheduler. It's a good point to contact TIDAL technical support how to access active desktop from their product.